# OR in `expr match`

Tags: shell-script, regular-expression

I'm confused as to why this does not match:

`expr match Unauthenticated123 '^(Unauthenticated|Authenticated).*'`

it outputs 0.

Comment: As an aside, if you were using bash for this, the preferred alternative would be the `=~` operator in `[[ ]]`, ie. `[[ Unauthenticated123 =~ ^(Unauthenticated|Authenticated) ]]`

Comment: ...and if you weren't targeting a known/fixed operating system, using `case` rather than a regex match is very much the better practice, since the accepted answer depends on behavior POSIX doesn't define.

Comment: See [Why does my regular expression work in X but not in Y?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/119905/why-does-my-regular-expression-work-in-x-but-not-in-y)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your command should be:

```
expr match Unauthenticated123 'Unauthenticated\|Authenticated'
```

If you want the number of characters matched.

To have the part of the string (Unauthenticated) returned use:

```
expr match Unauthenticated123 '\(Unauthenticated\|Authenticated\)'
```

From `info coreutils 'expr invocation'`:

> ```
> `STRING : REGEX'
>      Perform pattern matching.  The arguments are converted to strings
>      and the second is considered to be a (basic, a la GNU `grep')
>      regular expression, with a `^' implicitly prepended.  The first
>      argument is then matched against this regular expression.
>
>      If the match succeeds and REGEX uses `\(' and `\)', the `:'
>      expression returns the part of STRING that matched the
>      subexpression; otherwise, it returns the number of characters
>      matched.
>
>      If the match fails, the `:' operator returns the null string if
>      `\(' and `\)' are used in REGEX, otherwise 0.
>
>      Only the first `\( ... \)' pair is relevant to the return value;
>      additional pairs are meaningful only for grouping the regular
>      expression operators.
>
>      In the regular expression, `\+', `\?', and `\|' are operators
>      which respectively match one or more, zero or one, or separate
>      alternatives.  SunOS and other `expr''s treat these as regular
>      characters.  (POSIX allows either behavior.)  *Note Regular
>      Expression Library: (regex)Top, for details of regular expression
>      syntax.  Some examples are in *note Examples of expr::.
> ```

Comment: Thanks escaping the | worked. Weird, normally I'd excapt it if I wanted to match the literal |...

Comment: Regular expression syntax, including the use of backquoting, is different for different tools. Always look it up.

Answer (score 5):

Note that both `match` and `\|` are GNU extensions (and the behaviour for `:` (the `match` standard equivalent) when the pattern starts with `^` varies with implementations). Standardly, you'd do:

```
expr " $string" : " Authenticated" '|' " $string" : " Unauthenticated"
```

The leading space is to avoid problems with values of `$string` that start with `-` or are `expr` operators, but that means it adds one to the number of characters being matched.

With GNU `expr`, you'd write it:

```
expr + "$string" : 'Authenticated\|Unauthenticated'
```

The `+` forces `$string` to be taken as a string even if it happens to be a `expr` operator. `expr` regular expressions are basic regular expressions which don't have an alternation operator (and where `|` is not special). The GNU implementation has it as `\|` though as an extension.

If all you want is to check whether `$string` starts with `Authenticated` or `Unauthenticated`, you'd better use:

```
case $string in
  (Authenticated* | Unauthenticated*) do-something
esac
```

Answer (score 2):

`$ expr match "Unauthenticated123" '^\(Unauthenticated\|Authenticated\).*'` you have to escape with `\` the parenthesis and the pipe.

Comment: and the `^` may not mean what some would think depending on the `expr`. it is implied anyway.

Comment: @mikeserv, `match` and `\|` are GNU extensions anyway. This Q&A seems to be about GNU `expr` anyway (where `^` is guaranteed to mean _match at the beginning of the string_).

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas - i didn't know they were strictly GNU. i think i remember them being explicitly officially *unspecified* - but i don't use `expr` too often anyway and didn't know that. thank you.

Comment: It's not "strictly GNU" - it's present in a number of historical implementations (even System V had it, undocumented, though it didn't have the others like substr/length/index), which is why it's explicitly unspecified. I can't find anything about `\|` being an extension.